Bootstrap 5.3.3 JS bundle breaks 5.1.3 carousel pause button code
I wrote a webpage a couple of years ago that uses the Bootstrap Carousel component from Bootstrap version 5.1.3.
You can see a working version of it here:https://webdevschool.iimagine-websolutions.com/resources/book1/chapter1/module10c/application/car1-details.html
I was updating to Bootstrap 5.3.3 and the pause button broke.  If I replace the script tag for the Bootstrap JS bundle with the 5.1.3 version it works.
Then when I change it back to 5.3.3 it breaks again.
You can see the code from the working version link above but I'll paste it below for completeness.
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="device=width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Car 1 Details</title>
    <script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Site CSS -->
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Bundle -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
    window.onload = function() {

        $('#cars-carousel.slide').carousel({
            interval: 2000,
            pause: "hover"
        });

        $("#btn-pause").click(function(){
            console.log("pausing carousel.");
            pauseCarousel();
        });
        $("#btn-play").click(function(){
            console.log("starting carousel.");
            playCarousel();
        });

        function pauseCarousel(){
            console.log("pauseCarousel called");
            $("#cars-carousel").carousel('pause');
        }
        function playCarousel(){
            console.log("playCarousel called");
            $("#cars-carousel").carousel('cycle');
        }
    }
    </script>

    <style>
        #cars-carousel
        {
            border:1px solid black;
            width: 90%;
            margin:auto;
        }

        img {
           width: 70%;
        }

        #details {
            width: 90%;
        }

        .carousel-control-prev-icon,
        .carousel-control-next-icon,
        .carousel-indicators
        {
            background-color:black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
</head>
<body>
    <div w3-include-html="include/header.html"></div>

    <div class="container-fluid py-4">
        <h3 class="text-center bg-primary py-2" style="border:1px solid black;">
           2021 Dodge Challenger
        </h3>
        <!-- Bootstrap Carousel -->
      <div id="cars-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
           <!-- Indicators/dots -->
            <div class="carousel-indicators">
               <button id="btn-pause">Pause</button>
               <button id="btn-play" class="mx-2">Play</button>
               <button type="button"
                       data-bs-target="#cars-carousel"
                       data-bs-slide-to="0"
                       class="active"></button>
                <button type="button"
                          data-bs-target="#cars-carousel"
                          data-bs-slide-to="1"</button>
                <button type="button"
                          data-bs-target="#cars-carousel"
                          data-bs-slide-to="2"</button>
            </div>

           <!-- The slideshow/carousel -->
            <center>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="images/cars/details/car1/car1-details-1.jpg" alt="Car One" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Sexy Scoop</h3>
                        <p>on the hood!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="images/cars/details/car1/car1-details-2.jpg" alt="Car Two" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Muscular Back View</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="images/cars/details/car1/car1-details-3.jpg" alt="Car Three" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Luxerious Interior</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </center>

            <!-- Left and right controls/icons -->
            <button class="carousel-control-prev"
                      type="button"
                      data-bs-target="#cars-carousel"
                      data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next"
                      type="button"
                      data-bs-target="#cars-carousel"
                      data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <!-- end Bootstrap Carousel -->

      <div id="details" class="container">
           <h2 class="mt-4">Details</h2>
           <table class="table table-primary table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Condition</b></td>
                    <td>New</td>
                    <td><b>Mileage</b></td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Interior Color</b></td>
                    <td>Black</td>
                    <td><b>Exterior Color</b></td>
                    <td>Frostbite</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Drivetrain</b></td>
                    <td>Rear-Wheel Drive</td>
                    <td><b>Transmission</b></td>
                    <td>Automatic</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Fuel</b></td>
                    <td>Gas</td>
                    <td><b>Engine</b></td>
                    <td>6.4L V8 16V MPFI OHV</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>VIN</b></td>
                    <td>2C3CDZFJ8MH631199</td>
                    <td><b>Stock Number</b></td>
                    <td>MH631199</td>
                </tr>
           </table>

           <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Order</button>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="spacer"></div>

    <div w3-include-html="include/footer.html"></div>

    <script>
       w3.includeHTML();
    </script>
</body>
</html>

I just can't figure out why this line stops working in 5.3.3 as opposed to 5.3.1
$("#cars-carousel").carousel('pause');

I've compared the documentation between 5.3.1 and 5.3.3 and I don't see much of a difference.
Has anyone else had this problem in 5.3.3?

Well I got it all working. There were quite a few things going on.
Number one I had not realized that the carousel configuration code was never really working right even in my v.5.1.3 working version in the link I provided.
$('#cars-carousel.slide').carousel({
    interval: 2000,
    pause: "hover"
});

The interval was never set to 2 seconds.  It was always sliding every 4 or 5 seconds.  The [pause: "hover"] was working however.  This setting pauses the sliding when the user moves the mouse over the slide and resumes when he moves the mouse away.
To fix the interval I added the defer keyword in the script tag for the Bootstrap JS bundle.  This fixed the interval setting making the sliding every two seconds.
<!-- adding defer to script tag fixes interval: 2000 -->
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

To fix the actual problem this post is about, the pause button not working, I added [data-bs-pause="false"] to the carousel div element:
<div id="cars-carousel"
     class="carousel slide"
     data-bs-ride="carousel"
     data-bs-pause="false">

But I also had to go back to the carousel configuration and comment out [pause: "hover"].
$('#cars-carousel.slide').carousel({
    interval: 2000,
    // pause: "hover"
});

These two edits together fixed the pause button and now all of my original JavaScript and jQuery work from my original 5.1.3 version in the newly updated 5.3.3 version.
Also keep in mind when adding data dash attributes to components like the carousel, beginning in I think 5.2.x you have to use data-bs-* instead of data-*. For instance, data-bs-pause.
Here is the complete code:
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="device=width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Car 1 Details</title>
    <script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Site CSS -->
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Bundle -->
    <!-- adding defer to script tag fixes interval: 2000 -->
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
    window.onload = function() {

        $('#cars-carousel.slide').carousel({
            interval: 2000,
            // pause: "hover"
        });

        $("#btn-pause").click(function(){
            console.log("pausing carousel.");
            pauseCarousel();
        });
        $("#btn-play").click(function(){
            console.log("starting carousel.");
            playCarousel();
        });

        function pauseCarousel(){
            console.log("pauseCarousel called");
            $("#cars-carousel").carousel('pause');
        }
        function playCarousel(){
            console.log("playCarousel called");
            $("#cars-carousel").carousel('cycle');
        }
    }
    </script>

    <style>
        #cars-carousel
        {
            border:1px solid black;
            width: 90%;
            margin:auto;
        }

        img {
           width: 70%;
        }

        #details {
            width: 90%;
        }

        .carousel-control-prev-icon,
        .carousel-control-next-icon,
        .carousel-indicators
        {
            background-color:black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
</head>
<body>
    <div w3-include-html="include/header.html"></div>

    <div class="container-fluid py-4">
        <h3 class="text-center bg-primary py-2" style="border:1px solid black;">
           2021 Dodge Challenger
        </h3>
        <!-- Bootstrap Carousel -->
        <!--  Adding data-bs-pause="false" fixes Pause button -->
      <div id="cars-carousel"
           class="carousel slide"
           data-bs-ride="carousel"
           data-bs-pause="false">
           <!-- Indicators/dots -->
            <div class="carousel-indicators">
               <button id="btn-pause">Pause</button>
               <button id="btn-play" class="mx-2">Play</button>
               <button type="button"
                       data-bs-target="#cars-carousel"
                       data-bs-slide-to="0"
                       class="active"></button>
                <button type="button"
                          data-bs-target="#cars-carousel"
                          data-bs-slide-to="1"</button>
                <button type="button"
                          data-bs-target="#cars-carousel"
                          data-bs-slide-to="2"</button>
            </div>

           <!-- The slideshow/carousel -->
            <center>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="images/cars/details/car1/car1-details-1.jpg" alt="Car One" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Sexy Scoop</h3>
                        <p>on the hood!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="images/cars/details/car1/car1-details-2.jpg" alt="Car Two" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Muscular Back View</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="images/cars/details/car1/car1-details-3.jpg" alt="Car Three" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Luxerious Interior</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </center>

            <!-- Left and right controls/icons -->
            <button class="carousel-control-prev"
                      type="button"
                      data-bs-target="#cars-carousel"
                      data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next"
                      type="button"
                      data-bs-target="#cars-carousel"
                      data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <!-- end Bootstrap Carousel -->

      <div id="details" class="container">
           <h2 class="mt-4">Details</h2>
           <table class="table table-primary table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Condition</b></td>
                    <td>New</td>
                    <td><b>Mileage</b></td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Interior Color</b></td>
                    <td>Black</td>
                    <td><b>Exterior Color</b></td>
                    <td>Frostbite</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Drivetrain</b></td>
                    <td>Rear-Wheel Drive</td>
                    <td><b>Transmission</b></td>
                    <td>Automatic</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Fuel</b></td>
                    <td>Gas</td>
                    <td><b>Engine</b></td>
                    <td>6.4L V8 16V MPFI OHV</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>VIN</b></td>
                    <td>2C3CDZFJ8MH631199</td>
                    <td><b>Stock Number</b></td>
                    <td>MH631199</td>
                </tr>
           </table>

           <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Order</button>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="spacer"></div>

    <div w3-include-html="include/footer.html"></div>

    <script>
       w3.includeHTML();
    </script>
</body>
</html>

One last note.  Since I commented out [pause: "hover"] in the configuration I do lose the "Stop slide on hover" feature.  But I don't really need that.  I really do need the Pause button.  So this is the fixed that works for me.
